# automated uninstall

Tags: software-rec, automation, uninstall

Is there any application that can do this?Ive tried pc decrapifier but it seems to be needing a user in order to uninstall the programs that are checked. This is in windows

Comment: What are you trying to uninstall?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at [Absolute Uninstaller](http://www.glarysoft.com/products/utilities/absolute-uninstaller/)

[image]

> Probably the coolest feature is the
>   batch uninstaller setting that lets
>   you select a list of applications to
>   uninstall. You'll still need to
>   confirm each operation one at a time,
>   but as soon as one uninstaller program
>   finishes running, another will begin.
>   Overall, Absolute Uninstaller makes
>   the process of uninstalling multiple
>   programs much quicker and easier.

Credits to [Download Squad](http://www.downloadsquad.com/2007/08/21/batch-uninstall-windows-programs-with-absolute-uninstaller/)